# Execute externall compiled program in Python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I would like to execute an external compiled program in Python. In shell,

```
./bin/myProgram ./dir1/arg1 ./dir/arg2 arg3 arg3 arg4
```

And my Python script looks like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["./Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/bin/myProgram",
                 "/Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/dir1/arg1",
                 "/Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/dir1/arg2",
                 "arg3", "arg4", "arg5"])
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Solar/Desktop/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    "32", "0.06", "15"])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could you help me? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Evidently, your path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

when `subprocess.Popen` issues

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

that's only because the executable cannot be found (if one of the file-arguments was not found it's the sub-process which reports the error, and no exception is thrown)

In your case `./Users/...` is not likely to be valid considering that `/Users/` is valid (root against current dir) so that's your problem.

`"./Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/bin/myProgram"` should be `"/Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/bin/myProgram"`

Note: better coding could have avoided the error:

```
import subprocess
root = "/Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2"
subprocess.call([os.path.join(root,"bin/myProgram"),
                 os.path.join(root,"dir1/arg1"),
                 os.path.join(root,"dir1/arg2"),
                 "arg3", "arg4", "arg5"])
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you dear Jean!

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, I just had to execute

```
subprocess.call(["/Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/bin/myProgram",
                 "/Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/dir1/arg1",

...
```

Instead of

```
subprocess.call(["./Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/bin/myProgram",
                 "/Users/Solar/Desktop/parent/child1/child2/dir1/arg1",
...
```

Thank you people!!